# lost all my targets in my xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4

Newbie error: I erased all all the stuff under targets in my project. How can I rebuild/recover them? I can't compile or do anything and it also says I its missing the base SDK. Help

Comment: Cheeky comment: how about using git locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may well be better off creating a new project with the same name, and copying over all of your classes back into that.  It shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 1):

To add a target, right-click the Targets icon in the "Groups and Files" pane, and click Add...

To set the Base SDK, go to the Projects menu, and click Edit Project Settings.
In the window that pops up, click the "Build" tab.
In the "Architectures" section, set the "Base SDK" to "Latest iOS..."

Good luck!

Comment: I got all the way to the Build tab, but can't find the Architectures Section. There is a user-defined setting ARCHS...

Comment: Hmm... I presume in the "show" drop-down list, you've got it set to "all settings"? Oh, you can also set the Base SDK in the "General" tab, down the bottom, there is "Base SDK for all Configurations". I don't seem to have anything in my user-defined settings, so I don't know if ARCHS was something in the project you started with, or if it's corrupted somehow.